# Detecting online status when using service worker does not work

Tags: javascript, service-worker, offline-caching

I'm using google workbox to make some content offline available with service workers. The offline part works as intended. But I'd like to give the user a message (fe. with a popup or) when the client has network access again. I tried to achieve that with the online event listener of the browser. I opened the page with chrome, then i put chrome into the offline mode. After that I navigate to index2.htm and the offline content is displayed (=works). Then i put chrome into the online mode again, but the online-event doesn't get triggered. Does anybody knows why and how to fix that?

My files:

sw.js

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/5.0.0/workbox-sw.js');
if (workbox) {
    precaching.precacheAndRoute([{
        url: 'https://playground.test/index2.htm',
        revision: 1
    }]);
    self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
        fetch(event.request)
            .catch(function (e) {
                return caches.match(event.request);
            });
    });
}
```

index.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="index2.htm">Index2</a>
    <script>
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            window.addEventListener('load', () => {
                navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js');
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

index2.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page 2</title>
    <script src="offline.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Page 2</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

offline.js

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const handleNetworkChange = () => {
        if (navigator.onLine) {
            alert('You are online again!');
        }
    };
    window.addEventListener('online', handleNetworkChange);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem and I resolve this with this code:

```
  const hasInternet = (url = 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png?x=' + Math.random()): Promise<boolean> => {
return new Promise(resolve => {

  let img = new Image();
  img.onload = function () { resolve(true); };
  img.onerror = function () { resolve(true); };

  img.src = url;
  setTimeout(function () { resolve(false); }, 5000);
});
}
```